# How to break views exposed filters into more than one block. ie break few filters in one block and rest in another block?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-modules

I have four exposed filters in a view. I want to create 2 blocks of exposed filters. I want 2 filters in one block and other 2 in second block.

Comment: can't get what u r trying to do?!

Comment: I have four exposed filters in a view. I want to create 2 blocks of exposed filters. I want 2 filters in one block and other 2 in second block.

Comment: I have a quick solution but I wanna know first if you had created your own drupal module before?!

Comment: Yes I have made a module before.

Comment: Sorry for that, but have you tried to change the appearance using CSS ?!

Comment: Actually I want to place blocks of filters in different regions.

Comment: How did you finally solve this?I have the same issue..

Comment: I created a module to address this problem: https://drupal.org/sandbox/berliner/2087181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer to this question at this url:
http://www.undpaul.de/en/blog/2013/06/17/split-views-exposed-form

Solution::
In Views you are able to clone an existing display, which means nothing else but creating a plain copy of it. In our case I cloned the page display containing the exposed form to split and modified some filter settings only.

Other options (especially the page path) were not changed.

If you now look into the list of blocks, there is one block for both Views displays containing the corresponding exposed form. These blocks may be displayed on different pages and in different regions.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can create a custom module and implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)() to change the filtration form.

In order to be able to do that, you have to change the `weight of your custom module` form the `system` table. Make it anything larger than 10 (because it's the weight of the views module)

The you can implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)() to change the behavior of the form filters.

You can add any HTML after/before the filters using `$form['ANY_ELEMENT']['#prefix']` and `$form['ANY_ELEMENT']['#suffix']` OR using `fieldsets`. And then let the CSS takes its part.

The $form_id is normally formatted like that [views_form_`the id of the view`_`` `the id of the display ``]. e.g.: **views_form_my_view_page**

P.S. this is the only solution I could find for now.

Really hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: That doesn't address the question.